# Evitar dados duplicados em lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, lista

Eu preciso de uma lista de músicos sem repetições, porém está trazendo valores duplicados, de acordo com a quantidade de músicas que cada Músico tem, como faço para que seja trazido apenas um Músico?

```
public ActionResult SelecaoMusico()
{
    List<Musico> musicos = new List<Musico>();
    Musico musico;
    List<Musica> musicas = db.Musicas.ToList();

    foreach(var musica in musicas){
        int idMusica = musica.MusicaID;
        int musicoIdMusica = musica.MusicoID;

        musico = db.Musico.Where(p => p.MusicoID.Equals(musicoIdMusica)).SingleOrDefault();
        musicos.Add(musico);
    }

    return Json(musicos);
}
```

Comment: Você está repetido isso dentro do seu foreach. Você está adicionando um músico a lista a cada música que tenha o Id do músico incluído. ali está seu problema.

Comment: é sim, mas já corrigi isso, talvez não seja da melhor forma, mas a resposta está a baixo. Valeu @EdvaldoFarias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult SelecaoMusico()
{
    List<Musico> musicos = new List<Musico>();
    Musico musico;
    List<Musica> musicas = db.Musicas.ToList();

    var listaMusicasSemDuplicada = musicas.GroupBy(x => x.MusicoID).Select(y => y.First());
    foreach(var musica in listaMusicasSemDuplicada){
        int idMusica = musica.MusicaID;
        int musicoIdMusica = musica.MusicoID;

        musico = db.Musico.Where(p => p.MusicoID.Equals(musicoIdMusica)).SingleOrDefault();
        musicos.Add(musico);
    }

    return Json(musicos);
}
```

Dessa forma não haverá repetição.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um for dentro de outro for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < musicos.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < musicos.Count; j++)
    {
        if (musicos[i].PessoaID == musicos[j].PessoaID)
            musicos.Remove(musico);
    }//fim do for j
}//fim do for i
```

deixando o código assim:

```
public ActionResult SelecaoMusico()
{
List<Musico> musicos = new List<Musico>();
Musico musico;
List<Musica> musicas = db.Musicas.ToList();

foreach(var musica in musicas){
    int idMusica = musica.MusicaID;
    int musicoIdMusica = musica.MusicoID;

    musico = db.Musico.Where(p => p.MusicoID.Equals(musicoIdMusica)).SingleOrDefault();
    musicos.Add(musico);

for (int i = 0; i < musicos.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < musicos.Count; j++)
    {
         if (musicos[i].MusicoID == musicos[j].MusicoID)
             musicos.Remove(musico);
         }//fim do for j
    }//fim do for i
}

return Json(musicos);
}
```

Comment: Isso parece mais uma lambança. primeiro você adicionar e depois remover, dentro de 3 loops ainda.. veja a resposta abaixo se ajudar, se não sinalizer para vemos algo melhor

Comment: deu certo! muito tempo demais pra mim fuincionou

Answer (score -1):

Em vez de utilizar lógicas, você poderia utilizar classes que implementa `ISet<T>`, o `HashSet<T>`, por exemplo, não aceita duplicatas por padrão sendo uma boa opção.
Porém ele não trabalha com índices, se você quer trabalhar com eles é bom dar um .ToList().

Referência:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -3):

Uma solução mais simples e elegante.

```html
 BdnProdutos.DataSource = (((List<ProdutoDTO>)BdnProdutos.DataSource).GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(y => y.First())).ToList();
```